# Understanding Models/Controllers/Templates with ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to learn ember.js and having a difficult time trying to make the connection between it all.  I've gone through the tutorials provided on ember.js, but still a bit confused.

The model contains the data that will be saved on the server.  The controller has access to the model's data and can decorate it (add its on display data) and send that to the template itself.

In the examples, they use the route class to actually get the data from the model.  They associate the route with a model and just call .find() and that find() return you the list of data from the model.

I'm only using one route in my example:

My question is:

1. How do you grab data from the model from the controller
2. Can a controller get data from more then one model?  If so, how is this done?
3. If the controller has more then one function associated with it, how do you trigger the right one within the template.

Any examples would help... I've been searching around and in most cases they deal with the simple case where there is one controller linked with one model and the controller is linked with one template.  What happens if the template wants to use more then one controller?

In Reference to Mike's example of Template to multiple controllers:

```
  //index.html

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
     <div {{action getMessage}} > </div>
     <div {{action getTest}} > </div>

     {{#each App.menuController}}
          {{title}}
     {{/each}}
  </script>

  // app.js

  App.ChatController = Ember.Controller.extend({
     getMessage: function() { alert("getMessage Called"); }
  });

  App.MenuOption = Ember.Object.extend({
    title: null,
    idName: null
  });

  App.MenuController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
  content:[],
  init : function() 
  {
        // create an instance of the Song model
        for(var i=0; i<menuOptions.length; i++) {
            console.debug(menuOptions[i]);
            this.pushObject(menuOptions[i]);
        }

  },
  getTest: function() { alert("getTest Called"); }
});

//router.js
App.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('index', { path: '/' });
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return ['a','b', 'c' ];
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
        controller.set('content', model);
  },

});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: "index"
});
```

From the above, as you can see I have one route "index."  Within the default index template, I'm trying to figure out how to call multiple controller's action.  In this case, I want to call "getMessage" which belong to App.ChatController & "getTest" which belong to App.MenuController.  Currently, the "getTest" is not defined for the template's controller  "index" and has not be defined by the IndexRoute as well.  So do you use "needs" to link the MenuController to the IndexController so i can call the controller's getTest Method.

Updated ----------------------------------

I ended up going the render route

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return ['a','b', 'c' ];
  },
  renderTemplate: function () {
        this.render();
        this.render('menu', { outlet: 'menu', into: 'application', controller: App.menuController });
        this.render('userList', { outlet: 'userList', into: 'application', controller: App.UserListController });
  }
});
```

This allowed me to specify a specific controller for each specific rendering.

Any advice appreciated,
Thanks,
D

Comment: Curious if that answers your question or do you need more help?

Comment: This actually gave me a lot of insights and was really helpful THanks!!?  I've actually added more questions to if if you don't mind helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do you grab data from the model from the controller

By default, a route's model (the object retured by the route's `model` hook) will be injected into the controller and can be accessed via the controller's `content` property (also aliased as `model`).

> Can a controller get data from more then one model? If so, how is this done?

Yes it is possible. Additional models can be set on a controller from a route's `setupController` hook.  That said in most cases you will want to use multiple controllers.

> If the controller has more then one function associated with it, how do you trigger the right one within the template.

Controller functions are triggered via the handlebars `{{action}}` helper. The first parameter to that helper is the name of the function to trigger. So `{{action "save"}}` will trigger the controller's `save` function and `{{action "cancel"}}` triggers the `cancel` function.

> Any examples would help... I've been searching around and in most cases they deal with the simple case where there is one controller linked with one model and the controller is linked with one template.

The reason it's hard to find examples like that is because it's not a best practice. For sure it is *possible* to have one controller linked to multiple models or a template that uses multiple controllers but it's just not a good idea.

> What happens if the template wants to use more then one controller?

Technically this could be done by using global variables but please don't. Controllers are very lightweight. Each template gets it's own controller. If a template needs data from other controllers then it's controller should make that data available. This can be done via the `needs` property. See [managing dependencies between controllers](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/)

```
  {{each message in messages}}
    {{message.username}}: {{message.text}}
  {{/message}}
  {{input valueBinding="text"}}
  <button {{action send}}>Send</button>

  App.ChatController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['messages', 'currentUser'],
    messagesBinding: 'controllers.messages'
    send: function() {
      var message = App.Message.createRecord({
        username: this.get('username'),
        text: this.get('text')
      });
      message.save();
      this.set('text', '');
    }
  })
```

Comment: Why would it not be considered best practice?  Say that I have one url (route- index.html).  When you go to the index.html, you see a menu of possible options you can select.  When a menu option is selected, things get hidden and popups occur instead of redirecting to another page. When the popups occur, your access different data from different models and different controllers.

Comment: an example could be like facebook. When you sign on, and you have the chat on the side.  When you click a person, the chat window pops up and you can begin a chat.  I'm guessing that there is one route, multiple templates, multiple views, multiple models, and controllers. What would be a better way? Thanks for the answer thou!

Comment: Also how is a template associated with multiple controllers?

Comment: The thing that is not best practice is having a single controller linked to multiple models or a template that uses multiple controllers. For sure in complex app like you describe there would be many templates, controllers, models, and views. And while 90% of the apps will also have many routes, there are a small number of cases (like fb-chat use case you describe) where complex behavior would exist in a single route.

Comment: So in terms of best practices, my recommendation is to keep each controller as simple as possible and wire them together via `needs`.

Comment: Added an example that shows how a `ChatController` can access `User` and `Messages` models via their controllers and how the chat template would work.

Comment: Can you actually how me an example of how to access a controller's action method?This refers to a route accessing multiple controllers with different actions.  I looked at the documentation for the "needs" and also your example, but still not how It would be done.I'll create a new post below with the example I'm referring to.

Comment: I updated my question above with the detailed example of what I'm looking for.

Comment: Templates are evaluated within the context of a single controller. The `needs` array makes it possible for that controller to interact with another controller. I don't know of a way to get `{{action}}` helper to call a different controller, even if it's possible would not recommend it. Stick to one controller per template and avoid referencing another controller via a global like `{{#each App.menuController}}`. Instead use `{{render menuController}}` and define `menu` hbs template like `{{each controller}}{{title}}{{/each}}`