# How do you recognize identify caller of click event ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, onclick

I'm new to ember.js and was wondering how you would identify which div created the click event.

index.html

------------ old code -----------------------

```
 {{#each App.menuController}} 
     {{#view App.menuClickable}}
        <div id={{bindAttr id="idTagName"}}>
           {{title}}
        </div>
     {{/view}}
 {{/each}}
```

---------- updated code ---------------------

```
 {{#each App.menuController}} 
        <div id={{bindAttr id="idTagName"}} {{action selectMenuItem target="App.menuClickable"}}>
           {{title}}
        </div>
 {{/each}}
```

app.js

```
App.MenuOption = Ember.Object.extend({
    title: null,
    idName: null
});

App.menuController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
   content:[],
   init : function() 
   {
        // create an instance of the Song model
        for(var i=0; i<menuOptions.length; i++) {
            console.debug(menuOptions[i]);
            this.pushObject(menuOptions[i]);
        }

   },
   click: function(e)
   {
     alert("here");  
   }
});


App.menuClickable = Ember.View.extend({
  click: function(evt) {
    alert("ClickableView was clicked!");
    console.debug(evt);
  },
  classNames: ['navButton'],
  selectMenuItem: function()
  {
    alert("selected Menu clicked");
  }
});
```

As you can see, this will print out a couple of div's with different tag names.  I want to associate an onclick action event to each div.

From looking around there seems to be two ways:

1. Create a view like i have and overide the click function(e){}.  However, if I got this route i'm not sure how to distinguish between the different div and what triggered it.  I could look at the properties of the event (target->attribute->Id) but I feel like there should be a cleaner way
2. Use an action  {{action click "idTagName"}}.  However, I'm having issue implementing this action within the App.menuClickable.  It's not being triggered off and i'm not sure why.  I get the following error:

   Error: Nothing handled the event 'click'.
       throw new Error("Nothing handled the event '" + name + "'.");

I thought you would implement the click action like i have in the App.menuClickable.  Is there another place where this should be implemented?

Answer (score 2):

The `{{action selectMenuItem "idTagName"}}` approach is the way to go here. By default the `{{action}}` helper will look for `selectMenuItem` function in the controller's `actions` hash. If not found, it will be sent to the router, which will check the current route and any parent route's for a `selectMenuItem` function in the route's `actions` hash.

If you want to trigger a function on the view, specify it as a target like `{{action selectMenuItem "idTagName" target="view"}}`

Comment: I tried the {{action selectMenuItem  target="App.menuClickable"}} route, but it seems to not recognize the action "selectMenuItem.  Fire bug complains "The action 'selectMenuItem' did not exist on App.menuClickable".  Any advice on why i'm experiencing this.  I've updated the code in the main post to reflect What i've done.  Thanks btw for the responses!

Comment: try replacing `target="App.menuClickable"` with `target="view"`

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but no luck.  I think I'm missing a clear understanding of how the objects are all linked.  Example: Create index template -> that is associated to an IndexRoute --> linked to an IndexController.  When I add the same methods to all these, it works as expected.  IndexController gets called, if that isn't defined then the IndexRoute method is called.    However, I'm not sure why the view isn't working or does it have to be an IndexView instead of my menuClickable view.  I figure that you could just use any view with the "target".

Comment: related to as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500026/understanding-models-controllers-templates-with-ember-js

Comment: Will give this more thought but quick answer is that yes it should be an IndexView. I think what you are missing is that every ember template is _always_ backed by a view, even if you don't define one. So target="view" means target the current view.

Comment: So i guess the question really is then how do you associate other view.... "needs" that are not part of the direct association....to the one template many fields....It's weird the view's attributes..but not be able to call there actions...

Comment: See my comment in that other post, but basically you helpers like {{view}} and {{render}} - see http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36751/discussion-between-darewreck-and-mike-grassotti)

Comment: It's a bit wierd now.  I don't just use the controller to handle the action instead of the view itself.  Is there a reason why I would even need to user a view at this point?

Comment: No reason. It is pretty typical for an app to not have custom views at all.